# How can I change a toggle transition to start from top right?

Tags: jquery

I have made this jQuery code:

```
jQuery("#btn").click(function(){
  jQuery(".divs").toggle(500);
});
```

This works great, but the transition of 500ms starts from the top left. What if I want it to start from the top right?

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I tried both slideToggle and adding ('drop', {direction: 'right'}, 150) as well as 'left' without success. These made transitions from the top etc. not from top right.

Best regards,
Skt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the expand direction on .toggle()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799993/how-to-change-the-expand-direction-on-toggle)

Comment: Did you found an answer or net yet? Please Respond;

Comment: Hi, I tried both slideToggle and adding ('drop', {direction: 'right'}, 150) without succes

Comment: `jQuery("#btn").click(function(){
$("#divs").toggle('drop', {direction: 'right'}, 500);
});`

Comment: ah, I see, you want to put the } on the end, it didn't work. In your case it is also {}} - must be a { missing